# Impact Crater Simulation

Tags: simulation, astronomy

I have been trying to model crater formation on a given planetary surface - $500\,\textrm{km}^2$. The locations of impacts are random, however, if an impact is within $30\,\textrm{km}$ of another, the previous crater is considered eliminated.

So far I have used `RandomReal[0,500]` for both the $x$ any $y$ coordinate values on the $500\,\textrm{km}^2$ plot. My problem is that the arrangement of craters changes for every evaluation I do. What I'm looking to achieve is a cumulation of craters, one by one."Drawn on" so to speak. This way, appropriate crater destruction can also ensue.

I am also still trying to figure out a way to model crater destruction. As I mentioned, if an impact location is within $30\,\textrm{km}$ of another, the previous crater is eliminated. I tried using `If[EuclideanDistance[],...]` but no luck.

The code I used for crater location (points) is:

```
    craterlocations = Table[{RandomReal[{0, 500}], RandomReal[{0, 500}]}, {n}]
    p1 = ListPlot[craterlocations]
```

I need to produce a similar plot, but the craters should continually form. As of now I will always wind up with a different random arrangement for each number of impacts (`n`).

Comment: Can you post your code so we'll have a starting point? Also are your craters just circles in the graphics?

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov , for the purpose of modeling, points work fine. A crater is considered destroyed when its center is covered by a new one. That translates to a point proximity of 30km (crater radius).

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) [`Read the FAQs`](http://tinyurl.com/cacvex2)!  3) When you see good Q&A, vote them up by [`clicking the gray triangles`](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.  ALSO, remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [`by clicking the checkmark sign`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Very similar to Vitaliy's answer, but deleting all craters within the critical distance, and somewhat more compact:

```
craters = {{0, 0}};
number = {1};
Dynamic[
 (craters = #;
  Row[{
  Graphics[{PointSize@.05, Point@#}, ImageSize-> 230,  PlotRange-> 300, Frame-> True],
  ListLinePlot[AppendTo[number, Length@#], PlotRange -> All, 
               ImageSize -> {Automatic, 210}, Frame -> True]}]) &@
 (Join[{#},Complement[craters, Nearest[craters, #, {∞,30}]]]&@ RandomReal[250{-1, 1}, 2])
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: +1 very neat, is example of this syntax `{Infinity, 30}` in documentation on Nearest?

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov I used this http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/UsingNearest.html, and probably some remembrance of a previous answer in this site

Answer (score 13):

This is simplest implementation. If a new crater gets closer than 30 to some old craters, only closest old crater is getting replaced with new one. You can built on this example something more sophisticated.

```
craters = {{0, 0}};
number = {1};
Dynamic[new = RandomReal[{-250, 250}, 2];
 near = Nearest[craters, new][[1]];

 Row[{
   Graphics[{PointSize[.05], 
     Point[craters = 
       If[EuclideanDistance[near, new] < 30, 
        craters[[Position[craters, near][[1, 1]]]] = new; craters, 
        craters~Join~{new}]]}, ImageSize -> 230, PlotRange -> 300, 
    Frame -> True],

   ListPlot[number = number~Join~{Length[craters]}, 
    ImageSize -> {Automatic, 210}, Frame -> True]
   }]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Vitaliy, Thanks for the help. This is what I was going for. How could I find the number of craters after a certain time step? In other words, if a crater hits every 1000 years, how could I see the number of craters (or density) as a function of time? I don't see anything related to the rate or number of impacts in the code.

Comment: @BenjaminL Updated. History is stored in variable 'number'.