# Impact Crater Sim. with added criteria

Tags: numerics, simulation, astronomy

I have been trying with out success to edit [**this impact crater simulation 
script**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/37212/193) into producing a variable which calculates crater density. In addition I have been trying to figure out how to determine the time when crater saturation is reached. Where crater saturation is defined as the average number of craters in the test area changes by less than 5% when the time is doubled.

This is the code I have been trying to manipulate.

```
craters = {{0, 0}};
number = {1};
Dynamic[
(craters = #;
Row[{Graphics[{PointSize@.05, Point@#}, ImageSize -> 230,  PlotRange -> 300, Frame -> True], 
  ListLinePlot[AppendTo[number, Length@#], PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> {Automatic, 210}, 
                                                                        Frame -> True]}]) &@
(Join[{#}, Complement[craters, Nearest[craters, #, {Infinity, 30}]]] &@ RandomReal[{-250, 250}, 2])
]
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Just realized sending a personal message isn't a function on this website. Sorry again. Noob user here.

Comment: Don't worry too much about it. Each community has its own particular rules and it takes some time to get acquainted. Relax and enjoy. Welcome

Comment: FWIW @belisariusisforth's code crashes my kernel (`Nearest`  crashes on the second call )

Comment: @george2079 V9 gif updated on question

Comment: It turns out the kernel crash problem followed from initializing  `craters` to the integer list  `craters={{0,0}}`.  Making it real `craters={{0.,0.}}` makes it work fine.  Must be a bug in `Nearest` dealing with a mixed type list (V10.1)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach to implementing a steady state stop criteria by performing a regression on the last `n` values.

```
craters = {{0., 0.}}; 
number = {1};
nlast = 500;
tol = 0.001;
Dynamic[(
    craters = #;
    clen = Min[nlast, Length@number];
    fit = 
     LinearModelFit[number[[-clen ;;]], x, x]["BestFitParameters"];
    slope = fit[[2]];
    If[Abs[slope] < tol, FinishDynamic[]];
    Row[{ 
      Graphics[{PointSize@.05, Point@#}, ImageSize -> 230, 
       PlotRange -> 300, Frame -> True], 
      ListLinePlot[AppendTo[number, Length@#], PlotRange -> All, 
       ImageSize -> {Automatic, 210}, Frame -> True, 
       Epilog -> {Text["trend slope = " <> ToString[slope], 
          Scaled[{.8, .5}]], Thick, Red, 
         Line[{{Length@number - clen, fit[[1]]}, {Length@number, 
            fit[[1]] + clen slope }}]}]}]) &@(Join[{#}, 
      Complement[craters, Nearest[craters, #, {Infinity, 30}]]] &@
    RandomReal[{-250, 250}, 2])]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is fantastic thanks a bunch.